# find a name with extra chars between in a string python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am writing a simple code to find 'hello' in a string even if other characters are between its characters, e.g. : `hpepllpoo`.
But there are some problems.

My code is:

```
import re
x = raw_input()

if re.match(r'.*h+e+ll+o+.*',x):
    print ('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

For some strings for example `kdjhslfjhshhhheeellllllooooosadsf` print `YES` that is True.
But there is a problem. For example, my string is:
`helhcludoo`

The output is

````
```NO```
````

but I want to match it and print `YES`.

Comment: `h+` matches multiple `h`s, not `h` followed by other letters.

Comment: you need `h.*e.*ll.*o` something like that

Comment: You have the tag `python-3.x` for your question but use the `raw_input` function in your code. That function is in Python 2 but not 3. Which version do you really want? And do you think the version of Python matters for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way could be to use a [negated character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) class to match a character like `h`, then match not the next char `e` 0+ times `[^e]*` and then match the next char `e`.

Using [re.match](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.match), you could use:

```
.*?h[^e]*e[^l]*l[^l]*l[^o]*o
```

If you don't want to match newlines, you could use `\n` inside the negated character class.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JUchqg/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/CwhcjP)

For example:

```
strings = [
    "helhcludoo",
    "kdjhslfjhshhhheeellllllooooosadsf",
    "test helo"
]

for x in strings:
    if re.match(r'.*?h[^e]*e[^l]*l[^l]*l[^o]*o',x):
        print ('YES for %s' % x)
    else:
        print ('NO for %s' % x)
```

That will print:

```
YES for helhcludoo
YES for kdjhslfjhshhhheeellllllooooosadsf
NO for test helo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
h.*e(?:.*l){2}.*o
```

This basically matches zero or more of any characters (`.*`) between the desired characters.

`{num}` is a shorthand for writing successive repititive patterns; here, by `(?:.*l){2}` we're matching 2 successive patterns of `.*` (put inside non-captured group `(?:)`). So, you could also write:

```
h.*e.*l.*l.*o
```

Another thing is, you could use `.*?` to have the non-greedy match that is to match the shortest substring first, rather than greedily matching the longest with `.*` and tracking back.

```
h.*?e(?:.*?l){2}.*?o
```

**Example:**

```
In [2112]: re.search(r'h.*e(?:.*l){2}.*o', 'kdjhslfjhshhhheeellllllooooosadsf')                                                                                                                             
Out[2112]: <re.Match object; span=(3, 28), match='hslfjhshhhheeellllllooooo'>

In [2113]: re.search(r'h.*e(?:.*l){2}.*o', 'helhcludoo')                                                                                                                                                    
Out[2113]: <re.Match object; span=(0, 10), match='helhcludoo'>
```

---

In your Regex, you've used `+` which is meant to match one or more of the preceding token, so e.g. `e+` matches one or more `e`; hence your Regex will fail to match the desired substring obviously.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jean-François Fabre said, you need regular expression: `r'h.*e.*l.*l.*o.*'`

Here is the implementation with test cases to search `hello` in a given string:

```
import re

def check_hello(x):
    if re.search(r'h.*e.*l.*l.*o.*',x):
        return 'YES'
    return 'NO'

case1 = "kdjhslfjhshhhheeellllllooooosadsf"
case2 = "helhcludoo"
case3 = "nothing here"
case4 = "in between hello here"

assert check_hello(case1) == "YES"
assert check_hello(case2) == "YES"
assert check_hello(case3) == "NO"
assert check_hello(case4) == "YES"
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose another solution, not using regular expressions. In this way, you can give any word to find.

```
def check(x, word):
     if not word:
         return "YES"

     for c in x:
         if c == word[0]:
             word = word[1:]
             if not word:
                 return "YES"
     return "NO"

case1 = "kdjhslfjhshhhheeellllllooooosadsf"
case2 = "helhcludoo"
case3 = "nothing here"
case4 = "in between hello here"

assert check(case1, "hello") == "YES"
assert check(case2, "hello") == "YES"
assert check(case3, "hello") == "NO"
assert check(case4, "hello") == "YES"
```